# Super classes of one classe owl api

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I need to get All direct superclasses of one class from the ontology, and I need just named classes, not those gotten from equivalent expression with 'AllValuesFrom' restriction. 
I tried with the code below, it works for some ontologies that I create but others downloaded from the web (people ontology - pizza ontology) it doesn't work.

```
 public void motherclasses_Of_One_class() {

       for (OWLClass clss : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) 
       {  

       if(reasoner.getSuperClasses(clss, true).getFlattened().size()>1) // if the class has more than one mother class 
           {// System.out.println(" \n ---------------- : \n");
          System.out.println("\n  class "+clss.getIRI().getFragment()+" has more than one mother classes : \n");
          for(OWLClass parent: reasoner.getSuperClasses(clss, true).getFlattened())
              System.out.println(parent.getIRI().getFragment());

              }  

           }

       }
```

I tried with this version of code too, the same result as the first version

```
NodeSet<OWLClass> superclasses = reasoner.getSuperClasses(clss, true);
for (org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.Node<OWLClass> parentOWLNode: superclasses) {                      
OWLClassExpression parent = parentOWLNode.getRepresentativeElement();
                  System.out.println(parent.getClassesInSignature());
              }
```

the problem with downloaded ontologies, that it returns wrong superclasses for a class. I check the .OWL file, then the ontology through protégé, I can't find from when the problem comes. 
Please find below a wrong case to understand more what I mean. 
[image]
In the example, 'cat_owner' class has just one mother 'person' class. As you can see, pet_owner and cat_liker classes are in the same hierarchical level as 'cat_owner' class, they can never be mothers for 'cat_owner' class, and more than that in the description of 'cat_owner' class there is just one superclass 'person' class... but in the program output I get them as superclasses of 'cat_owner' class when 'person' class is absent form the list. I can't understand why... 
this is the output : 
  [image: enter code here]

Please if you have any idea that may help, I would be grateful. 
Thank you

Comment: "they can never be mothers for `cat_owner` class" <= What exactly makes you assume that? In the [people ontology](http://owl.man.ac.uk/2003/why/latest/), `likes` is a superproperty of `has_pet`, and thus any cat owner is also a cat liker by inference. In the same way, `pet_owner` is defined as a person owning a pet. Since cats are pets, every `cat_owner` is also a `pet_owner`

Comment: but here we aren't talking about direct and named superclasses (inference equality doesn't guarantee the hierarchical level that I'm looking for.. the semantic order yes of course )??? and why 'person' which is a direct superclass and declared one in the .owl file doesn't appear in the output ??

Comment: What --formally-- is the "hierarchical level you are looking for"? You can only ask the reasoner for information that is formally defined and this one doesn't seem to be (yet). Note that with `getSuperClasses()` "direct" means "not implied by another named superclass". And both `pet_owner` and `cat_liker` imply `person`, hence `person` is an indirect superclass as there are more specialized named superclasses.

Comment: The hierarchical level for me is the basic graph order, parsing concepts from top to bottom without taking into account semantic relationships and inference. that's why I insist to get direct subclasses and superclasses to get the graph - I named the basic graph - just after that, I'll treat every semantic axiom as an additional add for the graph.  Please, can you clarify the Note concerning getSuperClasses() how direct means "not implied by another named superclass" ...

Comment: Anyway, to make it easy, in order to have that basic graph, I need to return just superclasses mentioned in the .owl file as subClassOf, just like what we get with the opposite operation which is : reasoner.getSubClasses(clazz, true).getFlattened() that returns only children of class not children by inference ...

Comment: `getSubClasses()` will return inferred named subclasses, too. Basically any method attached to the `Reasoner` interface will perform semantic inference. If you only want the explicitly asserted superclasses, you can retrieve  the respective subclass axioms via [`getAxioms()`](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLAxiomCollection.html#getAxioms-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.AxiomType-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.parameters.Imports-) with axiom type [`SUBCLASS_OF`](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/AxiomType.html#SUBCLASS_OF)

Comment: I see , So I'll try with getAxioms() and axiom type SUBCLASS_OF . Thank you very much for shedding some light

Comment: By the way, there is no way to get superclasses by the same principle as what did you suggest "getAxioms() with axiom type SUBCLASS_OF " ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but given that `subClassOf` is `Sub ⊑ Super`, isn't that what you are already doing and you just need to switch which operand you look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. As described in the comments (which could be answers, really), you're assuming that `cat owner` cannot have `cat liker` as superclass, but I don't believe the data you've shown proves that.

> The hierarchical level for me is the basic graph order, parsing concepts from top to bottom without taking into account semantic relationships and inference.

If you want to navigate the classes without doing inference, you should not be using a reasoner for that purpose. You can navigate the asserted hierarchy by checking the subclass axioms in the ontology.

Comment: Thank you for helping.  Actually, I've just understood the difference between Asserted hierarchy navigation and the one doing by inference. when I need reasoner and when just checking axioms is needed. Thank you Ignazio and @dhke

Comment: @Ignazio: As far as I remember, there was some [structural reasoner](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/structural/StructuralReasoner.html) in OWL API, that works only on the asserted axioms + a limited subclass closure. Maybe this would be sufficient here?

Comment: It might be, but it's not clear to me what the requirements are. As far as I understand it, /no/ reasoning is desired.

Answer (score 1):

In the same context of this question, I have another problem, which is classes that have subclass axiom but with restriction, I mean not named class like the example below

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#Wood">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Wood</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#comes_from"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#Tree"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#comes_from"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#Nature"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

As you can see, Wood class have two subclass axioms but it doesn't concern a named class, unlike the example below; woodenChair class has two subclass axioms that are named classes : wood and chair

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#woodenChair">
        <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">woodenChair</rdfs:label>
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#Wood"/>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#chair"/>
                </owl:intersectionOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#Wood"/>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/Test2#chair"/>
        <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></rdfs:comment>
    </owl:Class>
```

This is the code I'm working on. The issue with it that it returns even Wood class as a class which has more than one subclass axiom; what I need is to check if it concerns named class or not ; I mean I need just subclass axioms with named class; can I have this result by using visitor or any oder method ? if you can help please .

```
 public void function3WithNamedClass (){

           for (OWLClass clss : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) 
           {  
               if(clss.getSuperClasses(ontology).size()>1){ 
                    System.out.println("\nAsserted superclasses of " + clss.getIRI().getFragment() + " : " + clss.getSuperClasses(ontology).size()+ " classes");

                     for (OWLSubClassOfAxiom ax : ontology.getSubClassAxiomsForSubClass(clss)) {
                         OWLClassExpression superCls = ax.getSuperClass();
                        OWLObjectVisitorAdapter visitor = new OWLObjectVisitorAdapter() {

                            public void visit(OWLClass ce) {
                          for(OWLClass superCls : superCls.getClassesInSignature() ){

                             if (!superCls.isAnonymous())

                                System.out.println(superCls.asOWLClass().getIRI().getFragment());

                                }
                            }      

                    };
                    superCls.accept(visitor);


                    }
             }  

    Thank you
```

Comment: No need for a visitor. `OWLClassExpression::isAnonymous()` will return false for named classes and true for anonymous classes.

Answer (score 1):

For the last issue, I tried by doing this (the code below) :

```
       public void WithNamedClass (){
           for (OWLClass clss : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) 
           {  
               if(clss.getSuperClasses(ontology).size()>1 ){ 

                   System.out.println("\nAsserted superclasses of " + clss.getIRI().getFragment() + " : " + clss.getSuperClasses(ontology).size()+ " classes");

                        for (OWLSubClassOfAxiom ax : ontology.getSubClassAxiomsForSubClass(clss)) {
                            OWLClassExpression superCls = ax.getSuperClass();
                                if(!superCls.isAnonymous())
                                {
                                        System.out.println(superCls.asOWLClass().getIRI().getFragment());

                                }
                                else 
                                        System.out.println("it's not a named class ...");
                            }

                    }
           }
 }
```

The problem with the code that will return all axioms with both kinds of superclass by doing this : `clss.getSuperClasses(ontology).size()>1`
and actually, what I need is to get just classes having more than one Named superclass; that means : the case of a class with 2 different subclass axioms must be ignored, because finally , it has just one subclass axiom of a named superclass ...